# Illegal string offset in PHP function

Tags: php, functions, metabox, warnings

I'm creating a metabox to upload PDF files.

I have the following warning notice for this line of code: `$this_file = $filearray['url'];`

*Warning: Illegal string offset ‘url’ in...*

The complete function code:

```
function wp_custom_attachment() {
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce' );
    $html = '<p class="description">Upload your PDF here.</p>';
    $html .= '<input id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" size="25" type="file" value="" />';

    $filearray = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true );
    $this_file = $filearray['url'];
    
    if ( $this_file != '' ) { 
         $html .= '<div><p>Current file: ' . $this_file . '</p></div>'; 
    }
    echo $html; 
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT

```
function add_custom_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'wp_custom_attachment',
        'PDF File',
        'wp_custom_attachment',
        'workshop',
        'normal'
    ) ;
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_boxes' );

function wp_custom_attachment() {
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce' );
    $html = '<p class="description">Upload your PDF here.</p>';
    $html .= '<input id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" size="25" type="file" value="" />';

    $filearray = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true );
    $this_file = $filearray['url'];
    
    if ( $this_file != '' ) { 
         $html .= '<div><p>Current file: ' . $this_file . '</p></div>'; 
    }
    echo $html; 
}

function save_custom_meta_data( $id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'] ) ) {
        $supported_types = array( 'application/pdf' );
        $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype( basename( $_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'] ) );
        $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

        if ( in_array( $uploaded_type, $supported_types ) ) {
            $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['tmp_name']));
            if ( isset( $upload['error'] ) && $upload['error'] != 0 ) {
                wp_die( 'There was an error uploading your file. The error is: ' . $upload['error'] );
            } else {
                add_post_meta( $id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload );
                update_post_meta( $id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload );
            }
        }
        else {
            wp_die( "The file type that you've uploaded is not a PDF." );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_meta_data' );

function update_edit_form() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
add_action( 'post_edit_form_tag', 'update_edit_form' );
```

Comment: Where is `wp_custom_attachment()` used? Is the current post always going to have a `wp_custom_attachment` field saved? Your code doesn't handle the possibility that there's no value. And if there _is_ a value, what does it look like?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I edited the question by providing the full code.

Comment: Ok, so think this through. When you create a new post, that post is not going to have this file, right? So how can `['url']` inside `$filearray` exist?

Comment: I understand, it's logic. However I'm struggling to resolve the issue. I'm starting in PHP so I block easily on this kind of problem.

Comment: I think I found a solution. Let me know if I'm wrong or right: `if ( isset( $filearray ) && '' !== $filearray ) : $this_file = $filearray['url']; endif;`

Comment: Say hello to the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary): `$this_file = ! empty( $filearray['url'] ) ? $filearray['url'] : ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be validating a couple of parts about `$filearray` before you use it.

There are some good suggestions in the comments, I think a couple of robust examples would serve you well too:

#### Using empty()

```php
function wp_custom_attachment() {
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce' );
    $html = '<p class="description">Upload your PDF here.</p>';
    $html .= '<input id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" size="25" type="file" value="" />';

    $filearray = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true );
    
    if ( ! empty( $filearray['url'] ) ) { 
         $html .= '<div><p>Current file: ' . $filearray['url'] . '</p></div>'; 
    }
    echo $html; 
}
```

`empty()` is great because it implicitly works like `isset`, whereby if the value isn't set it just returns `false`. Another benefit of `empty` is that you can test for structures like array keys without worrying about whether the object *is* an array at all:

```php
php > var_dump( empty( $a['foo'] ) ); // $a is undefined
php shell code:1:
bool(true)
php > var_dump( empty( $a['foo']['bar'][32] ) ); // $a is undefined
php shell code:1:
bool(true)
php > var_dump( empty( $o->foo ) ); // $o is undefined
php shell code:1:
bool(true)
```

Above, you can see that PHP isn't complaining about the lack of `$a` or `$o` being undefined, it just tells us "yes that is empty" and carries on.

#### Using isset and is_array

```php
function wp_custom_attachment() {
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce' );
    $html = '<p class="description">Upload your PDF here.</p>';
    $html .= '<input id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" size="25" type="file" value="" />';

    $filearray = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true );

    if ( is_array( $filearray) && isset( $filearray['url'] ) ) { 
         $html .= '<div><p>Current file: ' . $filearray['url'] . '</p></div>'; 
    }
    echo $html; 
}
```

This approach does two parts of validation - first, we ensure that `$filearray` is indeed an array, and then we validate that the `url` key exists. This is more verbose than `empty`, and has the added benefit of a type check. It should be noted that `empty( $filearray['url'] )` will *only* work if `$filearray` is an array because the syntax dictates it, however, this check is not explicit.

#### A note on ternary and null-coalesce

Some people suggested using a ternary:

```php
$this_file = ! empty( $filearray['url'] ) ? $filearray['url'] : '';
```

This is fine, though it's a bit hard to grok at first. You could also use null-coalescing if your PHP version supports it:

```php
$this_file = $filearray['url'] ?? '';
```

While these work fine, again, I'd avoid them until you're more comfortable in PHP. It stinks to come back to old code a few months later to try and remember what the heck you did when your code looks like

```php
$foo = $bar ? ( $baz ?? false ) : ( $done ?: 'Waiting' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much @phatskat for all the explanation and examples.